# Change Font style for keyboard in tizen wearable(Web application)

Tags: keyboard, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I'm using Roboto throughout my screens for tizen wearable. But wearable's system font is getting applied to the Keyboard's letters and alphabets. Do we have any control over the keyboard layout's font style from HTML?

Comment: What do you actually want to change ?  Key Board Layout's font ? 
Or the text you are typing ?

Comment: keyboard layouts font

Comment: have you tried to modify default ?

Comment: how to modify default font settings via code? I couldnt find anything from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can developed your own styled keyboard using [Tizen Web IME](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/text-input/ime-application) (Input Method Editor).

IME applications differ from other applications in that they do not follow the normal application life-cycle management and they need a mechanism to interact with the client application requesting the IME.

Tizen provides a special architecture to guarantee that Web IME applications work just like native IME applications (however, there are some restrictions due to the capability limitations of the Web applications in general). A Web IME application can be run within the core Input Service Engine process, which is also used to run native IME applications.

You can find Template of IME app in Tizen IDE.

**To create an IME application:**

1. To create the Web IME project, launch the Tizen IDE and go to File >
   New > Tizen Wearable Web Project > Template > IME Application > Web
   IME application.
2. Enter the project name and click Finish.

[image]

After installing tha app you have to change the **Text Input** from the **Settings**

[image]

Comment: It works great. But user has to select this keyboard from settings manually right? Can we handle this selection also from code??